# How to create Exponential Probability Paper in Python

Tags: python, plot, probability, exponential

I am trying right now to recreate this graph of the [exponential probability paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gWJq.png) in python.

In order to do it, I have to linearize the CDF function as:

```
x = a*g(Fx(x)) + b
```

and then plot `x` vs `g(Fx(x))`.

[This image shows the parameters for different distributions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxNSl.png)

However I am clueless about how to proceed. Apperently the scale of the x axis has to be changed. I already tried using probplot, but the result was quite the same.

Any ideas?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon
from scipy.stats import probplot

# Creating plot

fig,ax =plt.subplots()
newax=ax.twiny()
ax.grid()

# Lognormal

lambda_expon=0.04
i=1/lambda_expon

probs=np.arange(0.01,0.99,0.01) # array with probabilities

ppf =expon.ppf(probs,i) 
cdf=expon.cdf(ppf,i) 
x=-np.log(1-cdf) # variable
y=-np.log(1-cdf)*i # linearized form CDF

ax.plot(x,y)
newax.set_xticks([0.01,0.5,0.8,0.9,0.96,0.99])
newax.set_xticks([0.01,0.5,0.90,0.99])

ax.plot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, why do you think this is CDF plot. If on X axis you put probabilities, and on Y axis you plot `x`, it looks like quantiles plot.

I don't see in Python/Matplotlib built-in for such scales, `logit` looks like best approximation.

Or did I misunderstood your question?

Code, Python 3.8 x64 Win10

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# exponential distribution
def PDF(x, λ):
    return λ*np.exp(-λ*x)

def CDF(x, λ):
    return 1.0 - np.exp(-λ*x)

def Q(p, λ): # quantile
    x = -np.log(1.0 - p)/λ
    return x

# plots
λ = 0.04

p = np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, 101)
x = Q(p, λ)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

ax.set_xscale('logit')
ax.plot(p, x, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

and you will get something like

[image]

UPDATE

If you need probability plot, here it is

Code

```
from scipy.stats import expon

rve = expon(loc=0.0, scale=1.0/λ)

p = np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, 101)
x = rve.ppf(p) #  Q(p, λ)

q = rve.rvs(size = 10000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
   
res = stats.probplot(q, dist=rve, plot=ax)

plt.show()
```

and graph

[image]

Well, I already writing the code when you send a message. Placing it here anyway, it looks precisely like graph you asked about - linear with custom labels.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def linear(x0, xn, y0, yn, x):
    q = (x-x0)/(xn-x0)
    return q * yn + (1.0 - q) * y0

pmin = 0.009
pmax = 0.991

xmin = Q(pmin, λ)
xmax = Q(pmax, λ)

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 2)
p = np.linspace(pmin, pmax, 2)

tick_values = [0.01, 0.50, 0.80, 0.90, 0.96, 0.99] # probabilies
tick_names  = [str(v) for v in tick_values] # ticks to place on graph

tick_xvals  = [Q(p, λ) for p in tick_values] # x values for each p
tick_places = [linear(xmin, xmax, pmin, pmax, x) for x in tick_xvals] # x from linear function

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

ax.axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator((tick_places)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter((tick_names)))

ax.plot(p, x, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

and graph itself

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I am aware that this isn't a CDF plot. It is a Quantile Plot, but the X-axis ticks was changed to show the cumulative probability instead of the quantiles.

It seems I would have to manually add the scale to pyplot and that is out of my league ^^

Comment: Well, you asked about CDF transformation. ` but the X-axis ticks was changed to show the cumulative probability instead of the quantiles` this is (one of the) definition of the quantile function as inverse of CDF. CDF for given x return probability, Q-function for given probability returns x.

Comment: @LucasBarbosa I updated answer with probability plot. If you really need quantile graph as straight line, I'll cook it up after several hours, have to run errands. I'm just not sure what value it has with such non-linear scale.

Comment: Hi @Severin, 

Thanks again for your help. 
It is all good. I just wanted to recreate the plot in the figure as an exercise, to sharpen my matplotlib skills. I was actually more interested in recreating the non linear scale than in the statistical analysis. But as you said, there is no such scale already built-in in python and it doesn't seems worth it to go all the trouble of creating one.

Comment: @LucasBarbosa, I just put the code for linear graph, looks exactly like the code in the graph you wanted it to be. Still quite unclear how it could be used